# Shell Script to Kill a java process - Not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

My shell script which I wrote to find the process and kill it is not working . I have tried all the posts in stackoverflow but none worked out for me

Script is as below :

```
 pid=`ps aux|grep 'java -server -Xmx512M -jar -Dsolr.solr.home=. start.jar' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
echo Stopping Solr Server with PID $pid
kill $pid
```

Issue here is that while echo gives the proper PID say 12345
but kill throws an error

```
: arguments must be process or job IDs45
```

I do not understand why only last two digits of PID is being passed to kill?

Comment: If you have `pkill` then use that

Comment: If i run kill from bash shell manually it works fine.

Comment: Then use `pkill -f process_name`

Comment: It worked thanks.but why kill is failing from shell script but works if I write command in bash

Comment: @anubhava it is not giving any error but same time it has not killed the process.

Comment: Show us the entire script or a reproducible example. This works for simple examples.

Comment: Before kill add `declare -p pid` and show it's output here.

Comment: declare is not executing properly script is giving error : declare  -p  pid=`ps aux|grep 'java -server -Xmx512M -jar -Dsolr.solr.home=. start.jar' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'` output :
: not founderver.sh: line 1: declare: pid=12345

Comment: No no.. Use `declare -p pid` in next line after `pid=..` line

Comment: @anubhava Output : : not founderver.sh: line 2: declare: pid
Stopping Solr Server with PID 12345
: arguments must be process or job IDs 45

Comment: The error message `arguments must be process or job IDs 45` looks like `12345` is getting partially overwritten. Is there a stray carriage return character in your script, maybe in the `kill` line?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `pkill` available to you, it is better to use `pkill` instead of the long pipeline command:

```
pkill -if 'java.*start\.jar'
```

Regex `java.*start` matches any command line that matches `java` and `start.jar`